# Converting audio to code and vice-versa

Tags: audio

Having just witnessed [Sound Load technology](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEnfpQa3nrI&feature=related) on the Nintendo DS game [Bangai-O Spritis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangai-O_Spirits). I was curious as to how this technology works? Does anyone have any links, documentation or sample code on implementing such a feature, that would allow the state of an application to be saved and loaded via audio?

Answer (score 3):

Its the same old thing used in ZX Spectrum era. You load programs/games from tape.Only the sound quality and the filters are probably better.

In my opinion something like Bluetooth or WiFi is better. You can also send files that can be put on some storage and then load them. I find these methods much easier than sound because if there is a lot of noise around you cannot do much.

It is just a conversion of data to audio and then back from audio to data.

Search for Zotyocopy and Copy86M on google - these are the utilities used for saving a game to tape after loading it into memory on zx spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data as audio through the air there are a few things you need to be aware of though, such as how the speaker and microphone interact for example. It is important that they don't distort or alter the sound too much as what you are sending are in fact the raw bytes.
Some audio software will let you open any file as audio so that you may listen to it. If you record audio as data do not use lossy compression such as mp3 on the audio file!